# JAXB own object factory not used when unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2, objectfactory

Image you've got auto generated beans and you want to extend them with some extra functionality. So you extend the auto generated beans and in the same file you also extend the `ObjectFactory` and annotate it with `@XmlRegistry`.

When unmarshalling some object the extended `ObjectFactory` ins't used and therefore the auto generated beans are created.

What step am I missing to get my custom beans created? Can I tell JAXB which Factory to use? Or does JAXB not use the factory at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify the ObjectFactory when configuring your Unmarshaller.  I think you can use something like this to provide your own ObjectFactory implemenation:

```
unmarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.ObjectFactory",new MyObjectFactory());
```

Comment: I get a nullpointer exception when setting the property. Also there doesn't seem to be a com.sun.xml.bind.ObjectFactory class or interface in my classpath...